# SQL Server - Query Result where field cant = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to list rooms where there are no bookings on day 1

I have tried

```
select HotelRooms
from tblRoom
Where Day <> 1
```

This shows me the rooms in use on days not equal to 2. But I have a few rooms that are used on day 1, 2 and 3 and because of this these rooms still show.

I have searched and have tried to figure it out for hours, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: we are not familiar with you DB schema. So can please tell us what actually you are storing into it

Comment: how is day being stored, it sounds like you are saving day as a varchar/nvarchar and the days in use would be "1,2,3"  If so then your query is working exactly correct because it only returns Exact matches. if you changed it to select Rooms from tblRooms where Day not like '%1%', it would probably work but then if you had day 10 in there it would also not include that as well.  I would love to see how your schema is setup to give a better answer

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  a.Rooms
FROM    tblRooms a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        ( 
            SELECT  b.Rooms
            FROM    tblRooms b
            WHERE   a.Rooms = b.Rooms AND
                    b.Day = 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71dd1/2)

---

The records may be different from yours but the idea or thought of the query is still the same.

Assuming you have this records,

```
╔═══════╦═════╗
║ ROOMS ║ DAY ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║     1 ║   1 ║
║     1 ║   2 ║
║     2 ║   2 ║
║     3 ║   3 ║
║     4 ║   1 ║
║     4 ║   2 ║
║     4 ║   3 ║
╚═══════╩═════╝
```

the OUTPUT of the query above is

```
╔═══════╗
║ ROOMS ║
╠═══════╣
║     2 ║
║     3 ║
╚═══════╝
```

Comment: That worked great, if you dont mind me asking what does the a and b characters do?

Comment: @SimonJ they are called `ALIAS`. useful when you have longer table names. so instead of calling the table names, I used the alias.

Comment: [more on this link: \[the performance\]](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: +1 -- Thanks for posting that link.  I have always preferred the readability of the LEFT JOIN/NULL syntax but didn't realize there was a performance implication.

Comment: @sgeddes i'm also a strong user of `LEFT JOIN` :)

Answer (score 1):

I like the `NOT EXISTS` approach, but you can also use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT  Rooms
FROM    tblRooms
WHERE Rooms NOT IN (
   SELECT Rooms
   FROM tblRooms
   WHERE day = 1)
```

Or what I prefer, joining the table with itself and checking for `NULL` with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  a.Rooms
FROM    tblRooms a
  LEFT JOIN tblRooms a2 On a.Rooms = a2.Rooms And a2.Day = 1
WHERE a2.Rooms Is NULL
```

Comment: thank you, i will do more research on this not in.  this looks like it works too

Comment: @SimonJ -- no problem, glad we could help!